# What exactly is "only a read lock on the target table"

Tags: postgresql, locking, statistics

I'm trying to find information on whether it's safe to run `ANALYZE` on a large table that has stale statistics. The table is accessed in an "append-only" fashion and is constantly written to by numerous writers, so I'm concerned whether analyzing the table can block those writers for the duration of `ANALYZE`.

The [PG documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-analyze.html#:%7E:text=ANALYZE%20requires%20only%20a%20read%20lock%20on%20the%20target%20table) states:

> ANALYZE requires **only a read lock on the target table**, so it can run
> in parallel with **other activity** on the table.

What exactly is this "other activity" that can run in parallel if a read lock is acquired? Only other reads?

I then tried looking at the PG documentation to find what exactly a "read lock" is, and the docs for table locks don't event mention a "read lock" existing, but use some completely different terminology like "ACCESS SHARE", "ROW SHARE", etc.

Additionally, a few independent articles I found all mention that it's safe to use because it doesn't lock, and then proceed to quote the docs where it's clearly stated that it does lock.

I'm sure I'm missing something here. Does this "read lock" only prevent *definition changes* to the table while it's being analyzed (like a schema lock)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as is often the case, can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/75f49221c22286104f032827359783aa5f4e6646/src/backend/commands/vacuum.c#L1870) for the `VACUUM` command:

```
     * Determine the type of lock we want --- hard exclusive lock for a FULL
     * vacuum, but just ShareUpdateExclusiveLock for concurrent vacuum. Either
     * way, we can be sure that no other backend is vacuuming the same table.
```

and [similarly](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/d35a1af468162f510b6139bf81a7a41fd8ba8500/src/backend/commands/analyze.c#L145) for the `ANALYZE` command:

```
     * Open the relation, getting ShareUpdateExclusiveLock to ensure that two
     * ANALYZEs don't run on it concurrently.
```

We can then find in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) this fragment:

> `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` (`ShareUpdateExclusiveLock`)
>
> Conflicts with the `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE`, `SHARE`, `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`, `EXCLUSIVE`, and `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock modes. This mode
> protects a table against concurrent schema changes and `VACUUM` runs.
>
> Acquired by `VACUUM` (without `FULL`), `ANALYZE`, `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, `CREATE STATISTICS`, `COMMENT ON`, `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY`, and
> certain `ALTER INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE` variants (for full details see the
> documentation of these commands).

Answer (score 0):

Also need to be aware that running Analyze on a table will invalidate "blow the plan cache" for plans involving that table.    Causing new sessions to compile/regenerate new plans involving that table.   For a DB with small amount of sessions - don't matter.   Thousands of sessions - a bigger deal - a CPU hit for a bit until plans involving that table are regenerated in plan cache.  Always good to run analyze during low usage time.